# Does temperature cause electrons to vibrate more?

Tags: electromagnetism, temperature, electrons, electric-current

I read in textbooks that the mobility of electrons is affected by *lattice scattering* caused by vibrations of the lattice and by *impurity scattering* caused by impurities because they disturb the crystal's periodicity.

Both scattering mechanisms depend on temperature. The higher the temperature, the greater are vibrations of the lattice ions. At low temperatures, electrons move slower, they spend more time near impurities, so they are scattered more strongly by impurities.

So, I read about two motions affected by temperature: vibrations of ions, and the speed of a moving electron. However, there is no mention of vibrations of electrons.

Do electrons also vibrate more with temperature like lattice ions do? Does it change the size of electron clouds? What other effects does it cause?

Comment: Atoms are heavy enough that they can often be treated classically. But electrons are light enough that quantum mechanics is generally needed. That should guide your thinking. E.G. think in terms of energy levels for electrons, not mass on a spring.